# Running Java Parameters with Spaces In Them

Tags: java, cmd

I'm using batch and I'm trying to run a java application with multiple parameters. However, since my directories have spaces in them, java doesn't recognise it.

(I'm attempting to run minecraft)

```
java -Djava.library.path="c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\launch2\launch2\bin\Debug\libs\" -cp "c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\launch2\launch2\bin\Debug\versions\1.7.2\1.7.2.jar";
```

And so on and so forth...

The problem here is this part of the code `"c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\launch2\launch2\bin\Debug\versions\1.7.2\1.7.2.jar";`. The space in between `visual studio` makes this happen: `Error: Could not find or load main class studio`

Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Windows usually uses " for space separated parameters (like "Program Files")

Comment: @ceekay Yeah - I've tried that and it didn't seem to change at all - it keeps on ending up with 'Could not find or load main class studio'

Comment: Have you escaped the inner "? Because if you just write `-cp "path"visual studio"morePath"` it can mess up everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following. It drops the last slash in the library path.

```
java -Djava.library.path="c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\launch2\launch2\bin\Debug\libs" -cp "c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\launch2\launch2\bin\Debug\versions\1.7.2\1.7.2.jar";
```